# Httpurlconnection upload file trigger network lost for reset or resume

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

When I am uploading video to a server (Vimeo) with Android, everything is ok.

But during the upload, if i am loosing the network connection, i can't trigger .write I/O Exception From DataOutputStream.
So my app is freeze.

How can I trigger the exception to resume or reset my upload ?

My try / catch don't trigger the exception…

Here is my code :

```
private void call_for_ticket(String upload_url, String complet_uri, String videoUri) {

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(videoUri);

    if (sourceFile.isFile())
    {

        try
        {

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                    sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upload_url);

            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization",Aurtorizartion);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",accept);

            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");



            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "video/mp4");

            conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(-1);

            try {
                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                // create a buffer of maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                long bytesAvailableReadIncrementation = 0;
                long totalFileSize = bytesAvailable;


                try{
                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                    bufferSize = Math
                            .min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0,
                            bufferSize);

                    bytesAvailableReadIncrementation += bytesRead;

                    publishProgress("" + (long) ((bytesAvailableReadIncrementation * 100) / totalFileSize));


                }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("VMA", "lost connection");
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                // send multipart form data necesssary after file
                // data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                        + lineEnd);

                int serverResponseCode;

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn
                        .getResponseMessage();

                // close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                    call_complete_uri(complet_uri);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.d("VMA", "lost connection");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("VMA", "lost connection");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok So i figure out.

I am testing my code on the simulator.
On a real device, the exception is thrown :).